# Is there a state for currently clicked in css?

Tags: css

Is there a state for "currently clicked"? Lets say there are three links in the nav menu, how do you get it to keep a certain color when currently "on" the link? to show the user where he currently is. as :active only works as long as the link (in this case) is being clicked, but changes back on mouse button-release. –

Comment: Use Aaron Fitch's "checkbox hack" that you can see in caramba's link, if you want to avoid using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work "that way". One common way of dealing with it would be to add a body class on the page you are on:

```
<body class="about-us">
```

...then you hook into that in your CSS:

```
.about-us .nav .about { color: red }
```